# Log4Net on Godaddy Shared Host

Tags: c#, log4net, shared-hosting

I had Log4Net working on my Local machine. It logged to a DB with one FileAppender, Nothing logged to a file. When I moved my code to my shared Hoting provider (GoDaddy) I got an exception about FileIOPermission required. 
Does anyone have any ideas of what might have been happening?

I removed the configuration and am at the moment using ELMAH to log everything, (although I would like to use Log4Net) so I don't have any of the examples or stack traces anymore.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: When you say: "It logged to a DB with one FileAppender, Nothing logged to a file." ... Doesn't FileAppender append to a file? It strikes me that it would be particularly badly named if that weren't the case.

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was using ADONetAppender... I'm just fishing for reasons of why log4net wanted FileIOPermission when I wasn't writing to a file. I was logging to a SQL DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not much info to work with, but here are a few things you can do:

1. You can always debug the actual log4net code.
2. When it doesn't write to a file, it's usually a problem of
   permissions. If it's a web project,
   look at what user the application
   pool is running under (usually LOCAL
   SYSTEM), and that user needs write
   access to the file (and the
   directory where you want to put the
   file). The fact that the exception
   is actually FileIOPermission
   required definitely points to this
   direction.
3. Similarly, it might be that there is a temp file that log4net is
   trying to use when you're logging to
   a db. In that case, you might going
   to have to change your temp folder.

Furthermore, look at this post:
[Log4Net works on Dev machine, fails when deployed to shared host (using same db/connstring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542581/log4net-works-on-dev-machine-fails-when-deployed-to-shared-host-using-same-db-c)

Comment: I left the internal debugging writing to a file from when I was trying to debug on my dev machine... lame :) thanks for the temp file check it made me think of what might have been going wrong.